# identical css svg content url has 4px height more then svg tag?

Tags: css

Have no explanation for this?

[image]

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
i {
  display: inline-block;
}
i:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="black" stroke="black"><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/></svg>');
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<i></i>
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="black" stroke="black">
  <path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: First thing... shouldn't your `<i>` tags be enclosing the SVG?

Comment: nope `svg` tag is to compare it with the `i` tag, just press run to see two icons next to each other and then inspect height width from each individual one.

Comment: Oh, I see now. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the height of the `<i>` Tag  depends on the height of the font and not on some svg element. If you, for example, set `i {font-family: serif}` the height of the i will be 31px (here on my system, it may differ from your settings) If you want to have a fixed height for i you need to set it.

Comment: ok thanks, setting css width height 24 on both `i` and `i:before` worked maybe copy code snippet in your answer to showcase result

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed a font issue that you can easily fix by adding `line-height:0` to avoid setting fixed height:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
i {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height:0;
}
i:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="black" stroke="black"><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/></svg>');
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<i></i>
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" fill="black" stroke="black">
  <path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/>
</svg>
```